# How can i change the color of the rectangle made by the mouse when i press (and keep) the left button?

Tags: themes

Right now, in ambiance theme, when i left click somewhere and move the mouse (while keeping it) the rectangle that is made in order to choose files is orange. I would like it to be fully transparent or, even better, to have only borders

*tag is not good, i couldn't think of anything else though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appearance/*your_current_theme*/Customize/Colors/Selected Items/Background. That will change the color. You can play around and reduce the saturation, but I'm not sure how you will get a transparent effect. In my example I changed the highlight color in Ambiance to blue, and saved it as a custom theme called Ambiance Blue. I think that some themes don't support some color changes. If you change a color and don't see a result, try a different theme.

[image: theme color customization]